# Flex: How to determine if a PopUpManager window is open (or when it has closed)?

Tags: apache-flex, events, flash-builder, popupwindow

In Flex (Flash Builder 4) I am opening a new window via PopUpManager.addPopUp.  I have timer code that runs in my component and I need to stop my timer when that window opens and start the timer again when the window closes.

I figure it's easy enough to stop the timer in the function that opens the window, but how can I start the timer again when the window closes?

Is there a way to tell if there is a pop-up window in front of my component, or if a specific pop-up window is still open via PopUpManager?

Maybe events are a better approach?

Thanks!

Comment: You answered your own question didn't you? ;) Events FTW

Comment: I may not have understood your question, but it looks like you need to know if the popup window is closed. If it is the case, then I need to know if the window is closed. My question to you is, how are you closing your window. The usual way it to add a button and register a click handler on that button, that will call the Popup Manager to close your window. Are you  not doing that?

Comment: Yes, I am using PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);

Answer (score 0):

Events! is the way to go.
Fire events during launch/close. Add your logic in the event Handlers!

Comment: I like that idea, but (bear with my learning process), what happens if I have 2 of the same component and they both open a pop-up window.  Will throwing an event from pop-up window #2 end up sending over to both component 1 and 2?  (so how do the components know which event is meant for them?   or maybe I am wrong about that?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to check whether opened popup window is getting closed or not.
if it is closed you can stop the timer.

```
  //set the flag to find your popup window is exist or not.
  private var isPopupExist:Boolean = false;

  private function closePopUpWindow():void
  {

   var systemManager:SystemManager = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.systemManager;
   //Returns a list of all children.
   var childList:IChildList = systemManager.rawChildren;
   for(var i:int=childList.numChildren-1;i>=0;i--)
   {
      var childObject:* = childList.getChildAt(i);
      //If child object is Uicomponent.
      if (childObject is UIComponent)
      {
      var uiComponent:UIComponent = childObject as UIComponent;
      //If uicomponent is popup and class name is equal to **your popup component name** here i am using "ChatComp".

          if (uiComponent.isPopUp && uiComponent.className == "ChatComp")
          { 
                  isPopupExist = true;
          }
      }
   } 
}
```

in your Timer,

```
  private function checkPopUpExistance():void
  {
     call closePopUpWindow() function for every 1 sec or any seconds(your wish) to check whether popup is exist or not.
     if(isPopupExist)
     {
       here you stop the timer.
     }
 }
```

Now you can start the Timer, when you opened the Popup window.

Answer (score -1):

The popupmanager is a singleton class, so you can easily know how many popups have been created with his ChildList

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/PopUpManagerChildList.html